# JQuery Mobile : changePage changes URL but does not refresh the page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have been stuck for a few days on this issue. 
To simplify, I have 2 pages `(<div data-role="page" id="page1">...</div>` and `<div data-role="page" id="page2">...</div>)` and JS script that does a `changePage("#page2")`;
As a result, the URL is correctly modified but the page we see is still the first one. When I press F5 it refreshes to the second page.
I really don't understand why it does this, any help would be greatly appreciated !

Here is my simplified code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    $view->jQuery()->setLocalPath('/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
    $view->jQuery()->addJavascriptFile('/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js');
</head>
<body>

    <div class="tite"> Title</div>
    <form ...>
        <div class="zend_form">
            <div data-role="page" id="page1">
                <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false"> ... </div>
                <div class="title"> Another title </div>
                <div data-role="content">
                    ...
                    ... 
                    <a data-role="button" class="validPartial" href="#">Submit</a>
                </div>
                <div data-role="footer"> ... </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="page" id="page2">
                <div data-role="header" data-backbtn="false"> ... </div>
                <div class="title"> Second page title </div>
                <div data-role="content">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div data-role="footer"> ... </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <p>
        Some text added by JQuery
    </p>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.validPartial').tap(function(e){
                $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your problem is your page architecture. Page DIV parent must be only BODY. Don't wrap it in anything else.

Comment: and dont use `.ready()` with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the problem was finally solved by removing an import that was not supposed to be there. It works even though page div is wrapped in another div. I cannot change this, this is the way that ZEND Framework creates forms.